# Checking if multiple user-entered numbers are in the right range

Tags: python

```
str, ski = int(input("text here")), int(input("text here"))

    if str < 1 or str > 50 or ski < 1 or ski > 50:
        print("did not enter between 1 and 50")
```

Is there anyway to shorten the if statement in that code? I find that it is a bit too long, but I don't really know how to shorten it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When asking a question, *please make an effort to choose a good title* that tells the community specifically what the point of the code in question is. I have edited the title to this effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- This snippet is *not very useful*. You should not let the user continue after giving you wrong input; rather, as soon as an incorrect number is entered, you should figure out what to do next.
  (As you have not included any context in your question, this is left as an exercise to you).
- Your **names are extremely poor**:
  `str` is a library function and should therefore never be used as a variable name.
  `str` and `ski` are useless as they do not reveal what the variables are about.
  **Be expressive.**
- You are **repeating yourself** on a small scale: you are writing `int(input(...))` twice and the two portions of the if statement follow the same logic. **Get rid of the duplication.**

Consider these improvements applied to your code:

1. Use list comprehensions and generator expressions to your advantage
2. Use the `all(...)` function with a generator expresssion to verify that all answers are in the specified range

---

```
prompts = ('text here', 'text here')
answers = [int(input(p)) for p in prompts]
if not all(0 < a <= 50 for a in answers):
    print('did not enter between 1 and 50')

# if you need to access the answers individually, use
first, second = answers
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
attributes = {}
for attribute in ["STR", "PER", "END", "CHA", "INT", "AGI", "LCK"]:
    input_value = 0
    while not 1 <= input_value <= 50:
        print "Please enter a value between 1 and 50 (inclusive)."
        try:
            input_value = int(input("Enter %s: " % attribute))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    attributes[attribute] = input_value
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 *@instanceofTom* and you could remove some more duplication and create a more readable code with a named function which would tell the intent of the condition:

```
def is_valid_property(property):
    return 1 <= property <= 50

if (not is_valid_property(strength) or not is_valid_property(ski)):
    print("<> please write numbers between 1 and 50")
```

(Feel free to rename it, I'm just guessing about the intent.)

Note the changed message too. Error messages shouldn't blame the user (don't say what he did is wrong), give a suggestion about what they should do. (See: [Should we avoid negative words when writing error messages?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/48256/14623), [What will be the Best notifications and error messages?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/8112/14623))

Comment: This answer can't work for the [same reason](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42346/how-can-i-shorten-an-if-statement#comment72860_42347) as the other answer, and in addition `!` is a syntax error in Python.